# How do I "spot" enemies?

Tags: tribes-ascend

In Tribes: Ascend, I constantly see other players "spot" enemies which displays a voiced message to the chat

> [Spotted] (type of enemy) spotted (area)

and puts a marker on the actual enemy that was spotted (regardless if you or your base's sensors can see him).

[image: Spotted Enemies]

How do you "spot" enemies?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can spot an enemy by pressing Left Alt (default binding) when your crosshairs are over them.

http://www.tribesascendwiki.com/Default_Key_Bindings#Communication:

Comment: To add: Basically you can spot anywhere to convey some meaning to your team. "someone check this space, I think there's an infiltrator there"

Comment: @heishe Spotting will do nothing unless there's actually an enemy there. However, it still puts a marker where an enemy is even if that enemy doesn't have an IFF indicator (because they're at extreme range, or because they're jamming), so sometimes it's useful to just tap Alt to tell people "Hey, there's a hostile over there".